# CSS background width sized to document, not window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the green background color of this h1 text to go to the right side of the document, and be padded by the 50px that the body is padded in. Instead, it keeps sizing its width to the browser window upon loading. I'd also like to avoid setting a specific pixel width, as I want to use the CSS for a number of pages that all have different widths. I'm sorry if this has been answered already, I really have been looking for two hours.
[Here is one of the website's pages](http://dillon002.tk/snapchatpaintingsii)

and here is the css (note: the text is in an h1 tag in a #neon div)

```
#neon h1 {
font-size:16px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
padding:0;
margin:0;
background:#baebae;
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

}

```
body {
position:relative;
background-color:#eaeaea;
margin:50px;
padding:0px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/r4mhc8v9/

Comment: Swap body's margin and padding values. Add a length to `html { width: 100vw; }` and make `body { width: 90%}` or however smaller or bigger.

Comment: You're going to have to create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M). Include **HTML** with the CSS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r4mhc8v9/

Answer (score 0):

Try making the body margin and padding to 0. Then put everything BUT your neon h1 into a wrapper DIV (a div that holds the whole site) and put the previous body padding and margin setting inplace for this div.

You should be able to then make the green stripe go all the way...

Comment: either i'm doing this wrong, or it's not working. could you give me an example of how i would implement this in the html? here is my html

</head>
<body>

<div id="neon">
<h2>paintings</h2>
<h1><a href="/" title="back" >back</a>
</h1>
<br>
<br>
<ul>
<li>